# What does roswtf mean?

Tags: ros, roswtf

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello I' a beginner. Please let me know: What does roswtf mean?
I think ros is **R**obot **O**perating **S**ystem. But what the f... is wtf.
Its a tool for diagnostic and so on, but are the letters stand for? I confuse me a bit.
Please let me know that.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/277428/what-does-roswtf-mean?/) by [Hufeisennase](https://answers.ros.org/users/32885/hufeisennase/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2017-12-06

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Hufeisennase](https://answers.ros.org/users/32885/hufeisennase/) on 2017-12-06**:
I'm hoping for a funny sorry and i have no problems with anything it means :-)

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-04-15**:
Related/similar #q285116.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The official acronym is "Where's The Fire," but I suspect that wasn't the original acronym.

If you want more silly tools, go try to figure out what `rosawesome` does.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2017-12-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Hufeisennase](https://answers.ros.org/users/32885/hufeisennase/) on 2017-12-07**:
Thanks a lot. Yes "Fire" - so under 18 is welcome in ROS too :-)
I found this, how explain the spirit of the ROS names very well:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KPSyW1zGarA&t=40s

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-12-07**:
So no one has to do any Googling https://answers.ros.org/question/45463/what-does-rosawesome-do/